# Fitting a curve python

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I am trying to fit a curve in python with this function

```
def func(x,a,c,d,e):
    return a*((x/45)**c)*((1+(x/45)**d)/2)**((e-c)/d)
```

but I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

What should I do?

Comment: How are you calling the function? What are x,a,c,d,e ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast `x` as a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

def func(x,a,c,d,e):
    x=np.array(x)
    return a*((x/45)**c)*((1+(x/45)**d)/2)**((e-c)/d)
```

Comment: educated guess.  x is the independent variable in his function and if he naively made it a list, then you'd see this error.  Applying numpy array to it would fix that problem.

Comment: Usually you should try to avoid *guessing* answers

Comment: @Idos: That is a common enough error in this context. Whenever one tries to vectorize (i.e call with a list of values instead of a single scalar) a mathematical function, precisely this error crops up. So the intuitive leap wasn't all that big.